# Standard basis with relative coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L\colon \mathbb{R}_3[t] \to \mathbb{R}_2[t]$ be defined by $L(p)(t) = p'(t) + p(1) + p(2)t + p(3)t^2$. Find the matrix of $L$ relative to the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}_3[t]$ and $\mathbb{R}_2[t]$.

I'm pretty sure $p$ is not a function that takes $t$ as a dependent variable,
so I'm stumped. Where did those numerical values $p(1),p(2),p(3)$, multiplied by $1,t,t^2$, come from? Where did $p'(t)$ come from?

Comment: Please don't do any swearing in posts.

Comment: Your $p(t)$ is most likely a polynomial. Are you sure $L$ is not defined from $P_3$ to $P_2$? Here $P_n$ is the set of all polynomials less than $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose that $P \in \mathbb{R}_3[t]$ is the polynomial $a + bt + ct^2 + dt^3$. Then $L(P) \in \mathbb{R}_2[t]$ is the polynomial
$$ (b+2ct+3dt^2)+(a+b+c+d)+(a+2b+4c+8d)t+(a+3b+9c+27d)t^2. $$
As you can see, the coefficients of $1,t,t^2$ are linear combinations of $a,b,c,d$. Now just put everything in matrix form.

Comment: So, we're interpreting the notation ${\bf R}_k[t]$ to mean the set of all real polynomials of degree at most $k$? Seems reasonable, just not sure I've seen this notation before.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is the only interpretation that makes sense. I also have never seen this notation before.